# How to colorize an image with a macro in MS Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to addionaly put a slightly red transparent layer on an image in Word to indicate, that it should be deleted, because the change bar (when using the change tracking) is mostely overlooked.

So far so good, I can format the selected image:

```
Sub FormatPicture()

    Dim inShape As InlineShape
    Set inShape = Selection.InlineShapes(1)

    inShape.LockAspectRatio = msoCTrue
    'equals 16cm
    inShape.Width = "453,9"

End Sub
```

But how can I colorize the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
Dim inShape As InlineShape
    Set inShape = Selection.InlineShapes(1)
    inShape.LockAspectRatio = msoCTrue
       inShape.PictureFormat.ColorType = msoPictureGrayscale
    'equals 16cm
    inShape.Width = "453,9"
```

you can play with `ColorType`
I think `inShape.PictureFormat.ColorType = msoPictureWatermark` will suit your need

Comment: I still could not add a red layer, but `inShape.PictureFormat.ColorType = msoPictureWatermark` works for me.